# The range of functions defined by pure lambda terms

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

Consider a full set-theoretic model of the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus with infinite base types. Say that an element in this model is pure if it is the semantic value of some closed pure term in this model, and impure otherwise.

Intuitively pure functions ought to be blind to the differences between impure functions. This makes me suspect something like the following is true:

> If a pure function in this model takes at least one impure value, it takes every value (i.e. $[[\alpha]]$ is surjective if $[[\alpha]]$ takes at least one impure value.)

Is it?